# ensuring map access safety with atomic instructions, is Instruction reordering possible with 2 distinct atomics?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Problem:

I have `std::map` of objects called resources. A resource is an object which supports set/get operations of the members inside resource. A set OR get operation also does many other things which are performance heavy.
I also need to support an operation to delete a resource from map itself. So there is a possibility when there is a set/get operation is going on resource object. A Resource itself gets deleted and it would cause memory corruption.
*The Delete resource operation is very infrequent. once in billion.*

I have tried to use pthread read-write locks to achieve the thread consistency, but it has a performance impact. Later I tried atomics to solve this problem. here is the code.

```
std::atomic<bool> g_changeInProgress{false}; // used to block all reader threads
std::atomic<int> g_readers{0}; // used to block delete thread
```

*READER threads*

```
LOOP:
   while(g_changeInProgress) {
        std::this_thread::yield(); // give opportunity to schedule to other threads
    }    
    g_readers++;
    if(g_changeInProgress) {
        g_readers--;
        goto LOOP;
    }   
// DO SET/GET opration with the resource 
// this portion should not execute in parallel to delete
g_readers--;
```

*Delete thread*

```
g_changeInProgress = true; 
while(g_readers) {} // busy loop untill no readers left 
/* Delete the Resource here */ 
g_changeInProgress = false;
```

This code snippet seems to work fine for me and much faster than pthread read-write locks.
**Question:** In Delete thread is there any possibility compiler can reorder the instruction that would make this code to fail terribly?

Any lighter atomic lock implementation is possible than this?

Comment: These busy loops are *awful*. Yielding doesn't help because there may not be any other thread to yield to. Among other problems, they can waste CPU resources that slow the thread you are waiting for to a crawl. And, worst of all, when you finally stop waiting, you suffer a worst case mispredicted branch, a massive performance penalty at the worst possible time. If you care about performance *at* *all*, do not write code even remotely like this.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for insights. In my use case, It is Ok to compromise performance when a delete comes, Its a very rare event. Do you believe it is still not a good idea to use this code? Do you have any suggestion to improvise?

Comment: Your reader threads have the same loop with the same problem. What is the rationale for all this additional complexity? Do you realize how heavy `yield` is? And that it makes things worse if there is nothing to yield to. (My bet is that your claim that regular read-write locks impacted performance comes from testing under totally unrealistic conditions.)

Comment: Bluntly, if read/write locks written this badly are better than your platform's (or library's) read/write locks (correctly measured) then whoever wrote your platform's read/write locks is a terrible programmer and you should find a better platform/library. But much more likely, you're measuring very badly with some combination of using non-release builds, testing in artificially tight loops, or not accounting for the impact on other unrelated threads.

Comment: If deletes are so rare, why not just have the delete operation create a new map that's a copy of the old map and atomically replace a pointer to it that readers follow?

Comment: The last comment is effectively read-copy-update (RCU) which is a good strategy. The push back on the underlying problem is not incredibly helpful in that the measurement piyush is describing is not unusual for very rare write situations. The issue is more that robust lock libraries make a lot of guarantees that this design definitely does not. Personally I see Stack Overflow as more a place to ask and answer questions than to get into strong moral judgements about programming tradeoffs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yeah this seems a really good alternative. Let me get this clear, say map1 has 2 resources r1 and r2. one thread is operating on r2.get() operation. a delete for r2 comes. I copy the contents of map1(except r2) to map2 and start pointing to map2 atomically for any further operations. Is this what you are suggesting.

Comment: @piyush Yes, that's the basic idea.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz As per my tests. I did 5 million get operations on 16 core machine (16 threads, each thread is doing 5 million get Ops). With the current locking, it took approx 19s to finish. The same test with pthread read -write locks takes approx 57s to finish

Comment: @piyush That's clearly a very unrealistic test. Among other problems, it totally ignores the effect those threads have on other things the system is doing at the time. And the caching behavior will be totally unrealistic. I doubt that load looks anything like your real load.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I also did a 8 thread test on 16 core mahcine, In which this approach takes 9.6s and the pthread rw locks takes approx 25s. Can you give me little more detail here or point me to some read stuff. which can help me understand why would these tests will be very unrealistic.

Comment: @piyush Short version: They don't measure the things you actually care about, which is what effect the code has on the rest of the system and how it behaves when it's not called in a tight loop with things like branch prediction hot in cache.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for the help. I definitely have to go read more about this. It will give me clear idea. I would give a try to the alternate approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The default memory ordering for `std::atomic` is sequential consistency. This means no loads or stores can be reordered within a single thread with respect to an atomic load/store. Other threads establish an order by accessing the same atomic variable. Sequential consistency says one can construct a single ordering of all loads and stores, across all locations, across all threads. So in effect what you are envisioning is guaranteed. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model .

One can use less strict memory orderings to possibly increase performance.

This code will fail if there is more than one writer. Otherwise I think it works, but I did not try to prove this is so. Generally I like to have obvious invariants at each line of code and this is not perfectly clear here. I suggest you go through and state those explicitly to construct a proof of correctness once establishing the memory ordering properties.

A better approach is to use a single 32-bit or 64-bit integer with a few high order bits to track the state and then use the low order bits to track the reader count. Use `std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_weak` and possibly the `fetch_*` operations to update the state. cf The `SharedExclusiveSpinLock` implementation in this pull request to Halide: https://github.com/halide/Halide/pull/2420/files#diff-e05149e4d7a77708058562163bf8984d .

Comment: "This means no loads or stores can be reordered within a single thread with respect to an atomic load/store. " Since I have 2 distinct atomics. **g_changeInPrgoress** and **g_readers**. Are you suggesting that In Delete thread line 1 and line 2 cannot be shuffled at all? FYI.. This code is meant for only one writer.

Comment: Those two lines cannot be reordered. The memory ordering spec says things like "All writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable" The first two words of that sentence includes writes to *other* atomics. (It includes a larger set of things than assignments to atomics, but defining that set requires more words than a comment.)